# Filter the response of an observable and save to a local variable

Tags: angular, service, filter

I have a service that returns an ApiResponse object where the results is a vector of Client objects. The service works well, and the data is received correctly. The problem is that in the component where I want to render the information I need to filter the results of that service to show them in two sections, but this is not being possible since the filtered vectors are always empty. On the other hand, something I do not understand is that why when I try to display the vector clients per console in the OnInit it returns it empty, but I use it in the template if it gets the data and displays it.

This is my code:

```
export class PartnersExpirationsComponent implements OnInit {
  expirations: Client[] = [];
  expirationsWithoutDays: Client[] = [];
  expirationsWithDays: Client[] = [];

  constructor(
    private partnersExpirationsService: PartnersExpirationsService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  private getData(): void {
    this.partnersExpirationsService.getClients()
      .subscribe(
      next => {
        console.log(next);
        this.expirations = next.results;
        this.expirationsWithoutDays = this.expirations.filter(client => {
          return client.extraDays === false;
        });
        this.expirationsWithDays = this.expirations.filter(client => {
          return client.extraDays === true;
        });
      },
      error => this.handleError
      );
  }
}
```

Something I'm going through and I'm not realizing?

EDIT: This is the model that returns the next one when printing it by console:

```
export interface IARClient {
    info: {
        results: number,
        version: string,
    };
    results: Client[];
}

export class Client {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public numberDni: number,
        public email: string,
        public street: string,
        public phone: number,
        public alternatePhone: number,
        public birthdate: Date,
        public dateRegister: Date,
        public balance: number,
        public extraDays: boolean,
        public district: District,
        public state: State,
        public gender: Gender,
        public associationXClient: AssociationXClient,
        public id?: number,
    ) { }
}
```

[image]

Comment: "when I try to display the vector clients per console in the OnInit it returns it empty" -> probably because you don't know that getClients() is asynchronous.

Comment: Hi @Carsten, beyond that, which is correct and I understand, how can I do then to filter those results? First of all, the expirations vector is filled with the service response information, and then I want to use that vector which fills in information to create two new vectors but with the info already filtered from this original vector. Is this not possible? Is there any way to control such asynchrony?

Comment: What does the data look like in console.log(next);?

Comment: The answer returns an Object with all the data it just had to return. I will update the original question to add the model.

Comment: @Carsten, I really do not understand why I can not perform this simple operation. I have memories of having performed exactly the same operation elsewhere and obtained a correct result. Any help would be really great since I've been fighting this problem for a couple of hours.

Comment: Hmm, looks good to me. What does console.log(this.expirationsWithoutDays) show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh lol, i just found your typo:

You filter on extraDays and your returned property is extrasDays.

Enjoy your free time now :)

Comment: Right now I just realized my mistake. It's funny and even pathetic this mistake, but thanks for your time guys help me! Btw: I'm relieved to work a lot in a row, that's not a good idea.